# Cyrillic suddenly turning into question marks

Tags: html, character-encoding, internationalization

I've made an application which shows cyrillic text, but all of a sudden all the cyrillic turned into question mark signs inside a squared box. This has nothing to do with my script, as I checked my backup which is working and it was just the same there. Can it be something with my browser? I've tried to restart it. I'm using Chrome.

Comment: Do you have Content-Type meta tag in you html?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a `meta` tag that sets a `charset`?

It looks as if the Cyrillic alphabet uses `utf-8`.

http://webdesign.about.com/od/localization/l/blhtmlcodes-ru.htm